# The variabel in my program is not giving the value user already gave

Tags: c++, borland-c++, borland-c

I am right now learning about making a program using Borland, so this is my first time on use it. I got confused by the result, cause the result is not what I expected.

Below is my code:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
        char nama[25];
      char kelas[5];
      char jurusan[30];
      char universitas[30];
      char alamat[30];

      cout<<"Masukkan Nama Anda\t : ";
      gets(nama);
      cout<<endl;
      cout<<"Kelas\t\t\t : ";
      gets(kelas);
      cout<<endl;
      cout<<"Jurusan\t\t\t : ";
      gets(jurusan);
      cout<<endl;
      cout<<"Universitas\t\t : ";
      gets(universitas);
      cout<<endl;
      cout<<"Alamat\t\t\t : ";
      gets(alamat);
      cout<<endl;

      cout<<"\n\tBIODATA ANDA SEBAGAI MAHASISWA ADALAH SEBAGAI BERIKUT:"<<endl;
      cout<<"\n\nNama\t\t\t : "<<nama<<endl;
      cout<<"Kelas\t\t\t : "<<kelas<<endl;
      cout<<"Jurusan\t\t\t : "<<jurusan<<endl;
      cout<<"Universitas\t\t : "<<universitas<<endl;
      cout<<"Alamat\t\t\t : "<<alamat<<endl;
      cout<<"\n\nSilahkan tekan tombol ENTER untuk keluar dari program biodata singkat ini!";
      getch();

}
```

The result I got is kinda fine, but there is still one problem that I got here. Which there is one variable that don't show what the value of the user already gave, it did not show the value, it even just gave the word "u" which I don't understand from where this word was coming. I sent it with my picture, so you can see it.
[image: This is the image]

I hope you would help me, and thank you very much for reading my problem.

Comment: Why you are preferring array of chars (e.g. `char kelas[5]`) to `std::string`?

Comment: `#include<iostream.h>` -- This is not a standard header.  The correct header is `<iostream>`

Comment: Borland C++ 5 came out in 1997.  It predates C++ standardization.  So I have to wonder, why is this question tagged `c++11` and `c++-cli`?

Comment: @aldo Some arrays have too small size to store the entered strings.

Comment: @Gupta i just found it on Google code, so i don't know which one is better, and this is my first time on using c++

Comment: @VladfromMoscow how can i solve it sir? i still don't get it

Comment: @aldo *i just found it on Google code* -- Visual Studio 2019 Community -- g++ 8.x or above using any good IDE.  All these are free, better options than a 20+ year old compiler.

Comment: @aldo Make the sizes of the arrays greater. You are entering strings that are greater than the sizes of the arrays.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow no sir, the caracter of my array is 18(eighteen), and the size of the array i made was 30(thirty),

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have downloaded Visual Studio anyway sir, but my leturer wanted me to use Borland, so i have no choice for using any other compiler. Can you please sir, suggest me what should i do to fix this problem?

Comment: *but my lecturer wanted me to use Borland* -- So your lecturer also suggested to use `gets`, a function that from even 20 years ago, is dangerous to use?

Comment: the 'gets' is i am coding it sir, i just search on google and found one interesting basic program using **Borland**, so i used it. My lecturer just teaches us with Borland, and the study just happen once til we have to make a program with it

Comment: *i just search on google* -- Learning C++ via google is not the way to learn a language such as C++.

Comment: Emm, i am sorry to hear that sir. Maybe i am wrong in a way for learning this language, any suggestion from you for such a beginner like me sir?

Comment: Borland is so ancient it doesn't really fit current reasonable definitions of "C++"; it's more like a relic of when it was on the way to becoming the language it is. You would get more useful help if you can learn actual C++. If a course requires using Borland C++, I can only recommend dropping the class if you still can.

Comment: The arrays are too small for the amount you are typing in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After i tried some several suggestion to solve my own problem. Then i wonder, why there is just the variable of **Jurusan** which contain character that i don't know where it comes from. I tried to see it again, and then i reverse the place of another variable, also i put a comment sign `//comment to make it not being seen as a code by machine` in front of the **Jurusan** variable there is no problem anymore. Quite thinking, and then i just tried to count the sum of character in a variable which exactly below the **Jurusan** variable(**Universitas** variable), and then i also count the size of that variable(**Universitas** variable).

After this i just realised if the word "u" which in the variable **Jurusan** is the rest of the characther which comes from the variable below the **Jurusan** variable, which variable **Universitas**.

I am as the user, put the characther greater than the size of **Universitas** variable. And of course, that is wrong, and a mistake.

I came back to the code, and make the size of the variable **Universitas** is greater than before, and right now the problem is solved. And you guys can see it in my picture below if that is already succed, you also can compare it with the previous picture that i sent here in the Question section which has problem.

[image: This is the result that i expected, and you guys can compare it with the previoes one which has mistake before]

So, thank you guys for you who tried to help me. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

All of your input arrays:

```
  char nama[25];
  char kelas[5];
  char jurusan[30];
  char universitas[30];
  char alamat[30];
```

are going to be one continuous block of `char`s.  Your input methods will easily overflow from one array to the next causing all sorts of havoc.

Try using `std::string` instead and input from `std::cin`:

```
  std::string nama;
  std::string kelas;
  std::string jurusan;
  std::string universitas;
  std::string alamat;

  std::cout << "Masukkan Nama Anda\t : ";
  std::cin >> nama;
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout <<"Kelas\t\t\t : ";
  std::cin >> kelas;
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Jurusan\t\t\t : ";
  std::cin >> jurusan;
  std::cout <<std::endl;
  std::cout << "Universitas\t\t : ";
  std::cin >> universitas;
  std::cout <<std::endl;
  std::cout << "Alamat\t\t\t : ";
  std::cin >> alamat;
  std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: I'll try it sir,

Comment: it says _"Qualifier 'std' is not a class or namespace name"_ , do i need to declare some header first sir?

Comment: You will need to `#include <string>`.

Comment: Also don't use `.h` at the end of your `#include` names - that doesn't put them into `namespace std;` and isn't really C++.

Comment: I followed what you said sir, but it gave me another error like this _'cout' is not a member of 'std'_ and _'cin' is not a member of 'std'_, and do i have to put **using namespace std;** sir, after declare some of library in the heading?

Comment: I believe Borland C++ doesn't have any `std::` support at all.